# How to find out whether i have libidn?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, zimbra

I'm new to Linux, but i need to install the zimbra open source mail server on my server which is running centOS 5, in the system requirements in the zimbra documentation, under the other dependencies sections it is said that i also have to install libidn. 
 So my questions is how can I find out whether I have it installed & how can I install it? 
Thanks for your replies! 
 Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `yum install libidn` and it will either tell you it is already installed, or install it if it isn't.

Comment: But I also can't find the same about GMP &  compat-libstdc ++-3

Comment: Sure you can - just use `yum install gmp compat-libstdc++-33` for those (I assume you meant 33 as I don't think there is a 3).